# delete records in time ranges in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a lot of time ranges in TimeRanges table:

```
StartTime         EndTime
2010-01-01 06:00  2010-01-01 18:00
2010-01-01 20:00  2010-01-01 22:00
2010-01-02 06:00  2010-01-02 18:00
2010-01-02 20:00  2010-01-02 22:00
2010-01-03 06:00  2010-01-03 18:00
2010-01-03 20:00  2010-01-03 22:00
2010-01-04 06:00  2010-01-04 18:00
2010-01-04 20:00  2010-01-04 22:00
...
...
2010-02-01 06:00  2010-02-01 18:00
2010-02-01 20:00  2010-02-01 22:00
2010-02-02 06:00  2010-02-02 18:00
2010-02-02 20:00  2010-02-02 22:00
2010-02-03 06:00  2010-02-03 18:00
2010-02-03 20:00  2010-02-03 22:00
2010-02-04 06:00  2010-02-04 18:00
2010-02-04 20:00  2010-02-04 22:00
...
...
2011-01-01 06:00  2011-01-01 18:00
2011-01-01 20:00  2011-01-01 22:00
2011-01-02 06:00  2011-01-02 18:00
2011-01-02 20:00  2011-01-02 22:00
2011-01-03 06:00  2011-01-03 18:00
2011-01-03 20:00  2011-01-03 22:00
2011-01-04 06:00  2011-01-04 18:00
2011-01-04 20:00  2011-01-04 22:00
...
...
2011-02-01 06:00  2011-02-01 18:00
2011-02-01 20:00  2011-02-01 22:00
2011-02-02 06:00  2011-02-02 18:00
2011-02-02 20:00  2011-02-02 22:00
2011-02-03 06:00  2011-02-03 18:00
2011-02-03 20:00  2011-02-03 22:00
2011-02-04 06:00  2011-02-04 18:00
2011-02-04 20:00  2011-02-04 22:00
```

and I have some filters in TimeFilters table:

```
StartTime         EndTime
2010-02-01 00:00  2010-03-01 00:00
2011-02-01 00:00  2011-03-01 00:00
2012-02-01 00:00  2012-03-01 00:00
```

What I need is to delete the records from TimeRanges table, only those time ranges that are within the TimeFilters table will be retained.

To simply put, I want the following records retained:
from 2010-02-01 00:00 to 2010-03-01 00:00, like:

```
2010-02-01 06:00  2010-02-01 18:00
2010-02-01 20:00  2010-02-01 22:00
2010-02-02 06:00  2010-02-02 18:00
2010-02-02 20:00  2010-02-02 22:00
2010-02-03 06:00  2010-02-03 18:00
2010-02-03 20:00  2010-02-03 22:00
2010-02-04 06:00  2010-02-04 18:00
2010-02-04 20:00  2010-02-04 22:00
```

from 2011-02-01 00:00 to 2011-03-01 00:00, like:

```
2011-02-01 06:00  2011-02-01 18:00
2011-02-01 20:00  2011-02-01 22:00
2011-02-02 06:00  2011-02-02 18:00
2011-02-02 20:00  2011-02-02 22:00
2011-02-03 06:00  2011-02-03 18:00
2011-02-03 20:00  2011-02-03 22:00
2011-02-04 06:00  2011-02-04 18:00
2011-02-04 20:00  2011-02-04 22:00
```

What I can do now is to select those records are within TimeFilters into a temporary table, then truncate the TimeRanges table, and put back records from the temporary table, but that's quite time consuming.

Comment: What do you mean by "within"? Completely contained within one of the time ranges? Completely contained in the union of the time ranges? Overlaps one of the time ranges? If it is overlapping, should it be kept, removed, or truncated so that only the part that is completely inside the range is kept?

Comment: At the moment, this is going to remove _all_ of your sample data.  Is this expected, or is there an _identical, matching row_ that you've simply forgotten to include?

Comment: sorry, I did not clearly explain what I want, I updated my question, hopefully it will be better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete all the records in `TimeRanges` that do not have a match in `TimeFilters`, you can do

```
delete TimeRanges
  from TimeRanges r
  left join timefilters f on r.StartTime >= f.StartTime and r.EndTime <= f.EndTime 
 where f.StartTime is null
```

The tricky thing here is to do a `left join`, and delete those `TimeRanges` that do not have a correspondent filter (when `f.startTime` or `f.endTime` are null)

After deleting, you can see the results:

```
select *
  from TimeRanges

StartTime               EndTime
----------------------- -----------------------
2010-02-01 06:00:00.000 2010-02-01 18:00:00.000
2010-02-01 20:00:00.000 2010-02-01 22:00:00.000
2010-02-02 06:00:00.000 2010-02-02 18:00:00.000
2010-02-02 20:00:00.000 2010-02-02 22:00:00.000
2010-02-03 06:00:00.000 2010-02-03 18:00:00.000
2010-02-03 20:00:00.000 2010-02-03 22:00:00.000
2010-02-04 06:00:00.000 2010-02-04 18:00:00.000
2010-02-04 20:00:00.000 2010-02-04 22:00:00.000
2011-02-01 06:00:00.000 2011-02-01 18:00:00.000
2011-02-01 20:00:00.000 2011-02-01 22:00:00.000
2011-02-02 06:00:00.000 2011-02-02 18:00:00.000
2011-02-02 20:00:00.000 2011-02-02 22:00:00.000
2011-02-03 06:00:00.000 2011-02-03 18:00:00.000
2011-02-03 20:00:00.000 2011-02-03 22:00:00.000
2011-02-04 06:00:00.000 2011-02-04 18:00:00.000
2011-02-04 20:00:00.000 2011-02-04 22:00:00.000

(16 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I do all the time (though rarely to delete). As a note; this keeps `TimeRanges` that are completely within a `TimeFilter`.  For all `TimeRanges` that partially overlap `TimeFilters` change the join condition to `r.StartTime < f.EndTime and r.EndTime > f.StartTime`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is an outer join to get both the matches and the non-matches and then have a condition to extract the non-matches:

```
select * form TimeRanges r join TimeFilters f on
    r.StartTime between f.StartTime and f.EndTime and
    r.EndTime between f.StartTime and f.EndTime
where f.StartTime is null and f.EndTime is null
```

I don't know if the rest can be done with MySQL, but what you'll want to do is generate a condition that matches each each row that didn't fall between the dates in the filter table. The pseudo code to do this would be as follows:

```
cond='';

while (r = read row) do
    if (cond=='') {
        sep='';
    } else {
        sep=' OR ';
    }

    cond = cond . sep .
        '(r.StartDate=' . r->StartDate . ' and r.EndDate=' . r->EndDate . ')';
}

# Before running the delete query comment it out and run the query printed by:
#  print 'select * from TimeRanges where '.cond;
run query 'delete from TimeRanges where '.cond;
```

If this can't be done using MySql, then it can be done using a scripting language, such as PHP.

Comment: When I said MySQL, I meant SQL in general or whatever database you're using. Also, I mentioned that an outer join should be used, but the code was wrong and I wrote "join" instead of "left join"

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some sort of ID column on your TimeRanges table? If so, would something like this work for you?

```
DELETE
    TimeRanges
WHERE
    id NOT IN ( SELECT
                    tr.id
                FROM
                    TimeRanges tr
                    JOIN TimeFilter tf ON tr.startdate >= tf.startdate AND
                                           tr.enddate <= tf.enddate )
```

Comment: sorry, in TimeRanges table it does not have ID column, thanks anyway